# Chrome extension for capturing gmail events

Tags: javascript

I want to make a chrome extension which would capture every event occur in gmail like if i click on compose button an alert should be given that compose is clicked.

I am using content script but m not able to get id of particular element in which i want to add event listener.Can someone guide me over this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what isnt working. This is too vague....

Comment: For this, the easiest  way is to use inboxsdk or gmailjs. These libraries have event when you open a compose send mail etc. you just need to write a couple of lines

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail `Compose` button doesn't have an `id` property, but there are other ways to find it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => div.innerHTML == 'Compose' && div.addEventListener('click', () => alert('compose is clicked')));
```